# Is it possible to have 4 hardware PWMs on RPi 5?

Tags: pwm, pi-5

Some internet resources mentioned that RP1 chip on RPi 5 has 4-channel PWM output. For example, [this one](https://community.element14.com/products/raspberry-pi/m/files/148385). I was able to make 2 outputs working by adding `dtoverlay=pwm-2chan` to `/boot/firmware/config.txt` and using the script below.
However, I can not figure out if and how the one can get 4 hardware PWM outputs. I would appreciate any hints.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Pin 12 (GPIO18)
CHANNEL=2
CHIP=pwmchip2
PWM=pwm$CHANNEL

echo $CHANNEL > /sys/class/pwm/$CHIP/export
sleep 1
# Servo frequency 50Hz period 20mSec (20,000,000nSec) pulse_width 1.5mSec (1,500,000nSec)
echo 20000000 > /sys/class/pwm/$CHIP/$PWM/period
echo 1500000 > /sys/class/pwm/$CHIP/$PWM/duty_cycle
echo 1 > /sys/class/pwm/$CHIP/$PWM/enable

# Pin 35 (GPIO19)
CHANNEL=3
PWM=pwm$CHANNEL

echo $CHANNEL > /sys/class/pwm/$CHIP/export
sleep 1
# Servo frequency 50Hz period 20mSec (20,000,000nSec) pulse_width 1.5mSec (1,500,000nSec)
echo 20000000 > /sys/class/pwm/$CHIP/$PWM/period
echo 1500000 > /sys/class/pwm/$CHIP/$PWM/duty_cycle
echo 1 > /sys/class/pwm/$CHIP/$PWM/enable
```

Answer (score 1):

The Pi5 does have appear to have 4 PWM channels on pwmchip2.
pwmchip0 has 2 of which are accessible on the 40 pin header. It appears only one pair can be activated at a time (unlike earlier Pi).

One (GPIO45) is used for the fan on the fan connector.

I am unaware of any software to use it for any other purpose.

I am still trying to get hardware PWM working on the normal pins.

There are still the emulated PWM; lgpio seems to provide reliable PWM.

Comment: "The Pi5 does have appear to have 4 PWM channels on pwmchip2." - this is what I am also reading. But do you know how to activate all of them? Two are working just fine but I am wondering how to make the other two working?